# Send push notifications using FCM XMPP protocol within the PHP application

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is any way to send push notification on android and iOS device using FCM XMPP protocol from my PHP based application/web services?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? These search results seem quite promising: https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20xmpp%20chat%20script&rct=j

Comment: I couldn't find anything sensible. There is [FCMStream](https://github.com/sourc7/FCMStream) but it should be considered rather as proof of concept, not production ready. I've tried to build something based on [JAXL](https://github.com/jaxl/JAXL) but finally decided to build something of my own. I will post a link to it, when it will be ready to show (I hope that it will be in a month or so).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer late for those who arrive on this page.

Take a look at [Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-FCM-XMPP](https://github.com/baudev/Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-FCM-XMPP). This repository is based on the [FCMStream](https://github.com/sourc7/FCMStream) POC, which contains a lot of bugs and unmanaged cases. [Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-FCM-XMPP](https://github.com/baudev/Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-FCM-XMPP) is fully working (I use it today in production).